# Rails calendar_date_select can't display calendar on browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I installed the calendar_date_select with the following steps

add to gemfile

```
# To use calendar_date_select
gem 'calendar_date_select', :git => 'git://github.com/paneq/calendar_date_select.git'
```

bundle install

```
bundle install
```

my application.html.erb looks like

```
<head>
  <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "prototype" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %> 
  <%= calendar_date_select_includes "silver" %>     
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
</head>
```

And then I used this line to fetch data from a calendar.

```
<%= calendar_date_select_tag "startdate", nil, :embedded => true, :year_range =>  10.years.ago..0.years.ago %>
```

and this is how the page source looks like

```
<input id="startdate" name="startdate" type="hidden" /><span id="cds_placeholder_89036" style="display: none; position: absolute;"></span><script type="text/javascript">
```

//

But I simply cannot see the plugin on my browser.

Answer (score 0):

The javascripts probably aren't being loaded on the page.  You might need to add `<%= calendar_date_select_includes %>` in the head section of your layouts.

EDIT 1: Sorry, I see it now in your source.

EDIT 2: `<%= calendar_date_select_includes "silver" %>` should be after `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`

Comment: I tried to move <%= calendar_date_select_includes "silver" %> after <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>, but it did not help